# Kotin lateinit Var Not initialized - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-lateinit

I am working on a simple contact app that stores the contact's name, email, and number. 
Language: Kotlin
Architecture: MVVM
But I am getting an error: `lateinit property addContactViewModel has not been initialized`

> **Activity:**

```
class AddContact : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var addContactViewModel : AddContactViewModel

companion object{
    const val EXTRA_REPLY = "com.room.contacts.REPLY"
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val binding  = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityAddContactBinding>(
        this,R.layout.activity_add_contact
    )

    binding.btnSave.setOnClickListener {
        val replyIntent = Intent()
        val fname= binding.fnameEdit.text.toString()
        val lname= binding.lnameEdit.text.toString()
        val email = binding.emailAddressEdit.text.toString()
        val contactno = binding.contactNumberEdit.text.toString()
        val contact = Contact(fname, lname,email,contactno)
        addContactViewModel.insert(contact)
        val intent = Intent(this, ContactList::class.java)
        // start your next activity
        startActivity(intent)
    }

}}
```

> **ViewModel:**

```
class AddContactViewModel (application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application){

private val repository: ContactRepository

init {
    val contactsDao= ContactRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application).contactDao()
    repository = ContactRepository(contactsDao)
}

fun insert(contact: Contact) = viewModelScope.launch {
    repository.insert(contact)
}}
```

> **Error:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.room.contacts, PID: 29383
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property addContactViewModel has not been initialized
    at com.room.contacts.screens.addContact.AddContact.access$getAddContactViewModel$p(AddContact.kt:15)
    at com.room.contacts.screens.addContact.AddContact$onCreate$1.onClick(AddContact.kt:36)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4781)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19907)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

Comment: You should initialize addContactViewModel in oncreate, not in setOnClickListener

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin yes! that makes sense! resolved it like that. Thanks

Comment: Why did you change the correct answer?

Comment: Your answer is correct as well. I dig deep into it and seems like the better way to do things is to use the lazy property. Your answer is correct but the other one seems like a better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having your `addContactViewModel` as a `lateinit` property you can make it a `lazy` property, so that it gets initialized the first time you try to use it somewhere:

```
class AddContact : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val addContactViewModel : AddContactViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(AddContactViewModel::class.java)
    }
```

Comment: this works too! But rather than instantiating the lateinit var in the listener, I instantiated it in onCreate and that worked for me. This Solution works as well.

Comment: Yeah, both work. But a `lazy` property has the benefit that you can't forget to initialize it. And you can make it a `val`, unlike a `lateinit` property which must be a `var`.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize addContactViewModel in oncreate, not in setOnClickListener