# lateinit property has not been initialized when get data from array list

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I want to get the first index from arraylist data that i got from API using retrofit

```
c

lass BeritaActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var listData : ArrayList<Berita> = ArrayList()
    lateinit var adapter: BeritaAdapter

    lateinit var image_headline: String
    lateinit var judul_headline: String

    companion object {
        const val JUDUL = "judul"
        const val BERITA = "berita"
        const val IMAGE = "image"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_berita)



        recycler_berita.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recycler_berita.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)

        ApiService.create()
            .getBerita()
            .enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<List<Berita>>{
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Berita>>, t: Throwable) {
                    toast(t.message.toString())
                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<List<Berita>>,
                    response: Response<List<Berita>>
                ) {
                    listData.addAll(response.body() as ArrayList<Berita>)
                    judul_headline = listData[0].namaKegiatan.toString()
                    image_headline = listData[0].foto.toString()
                    Log.d("Headline Judul",judul_headline)
                    Log.d("Headline Photo",image_headline)
                    adapter = BeritaAdapter(listData, this@BeritaActivity){
                        startActivity<DetailBeritaActivity>(
                            JUDUL to it.namaKegiatan,
                            BERITA to it.deskripsiKegiatan,
                            IMAGE to it.foto
                        )
                    }

                    recycler_berita.adapter = adapter
                }

            })


        judul_headline_berita.text =  judul_headline
        Glide.with(this)
            .load("https://tahfidzta.doaqu.or.id/kegiatan/"+image_headline)
            .into(image_headline_berita)
    }
}
```

and got this error

> 2020-05-21 21:10:31.309 1726-1726/com.thor.prototype E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.thor.prototype, PID: 1726
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thor.prototype/com.thor.doaqu.BeritaActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property judul_headline has not been initialized
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
>        Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property judul_headline has not been initialized
>           at com.thor.doaqu.BeritaActivity.onCreate(BeritaActivity.kt:74)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)

I dunno whats wrong with it, please help me 
Thank you

Comment: `enqueue` is async, there is no guarantee that `onResponse` will be executed before `judul_headline_berita.text = judul_headline`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize `lateinit` variable in `onCreate` function or using `lazy`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61414278/12478830

You can use easily instead of

```
lateinit var image_headline: String
    lateinit var judul_headline: String
```

this lines

```
  var image_headline=""
   var judul_headline=""
```

Comment: i had been tried initialize it in onCreate but still same, any idea how using lazy?

Comment: I modified my answer. @ThoriqulUmar

Comment: My answer is modified again @ThoriqulUmar

Answer (score 0):

It happened because `enqueue()` works asynchronously. That's mean this bloc of code

```
judul_headline_berita.text =  judul_headline
Glide.with(this)
    .load("https://tahfidzta.doaqu.or.id/kegiatan/"+image_headline)
    .into(image_headline_berita)
```

will be execute first and here `image_headline` isn't initialized.
So solution is:

```
 override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<Berita>>,
                response: Response<List<Berita>>
            ) {
                listData.addAll(response.body() as ArrayList<Berita>)
                judul_headline = listData[0].namaKegiatan.toString()
                image_headline = listData[0].foto.toString()
                Log.d("Headline Judul",judul_headline)
                Log.d("Headline Photo",image_headline)
                adapter = BeritaAdapter(listData, this@BeritaActivity){
                    startActivity<DetailBeritaActivity>(
                        JUDUL to it.namaKegiatan,
                        BERITA to it.deskripsiKegiatan,
                        IMAGE to it.foto
                    )
                }

                recycler_berita.adapter = adapter

                judul_headline_berita.text =  judul_headline
                Glide.with(this)
               .load("https://tahfidzta.doaqu.or.id/kegiatan/"+image_headline)
               .into(image_headline_berita)
            }
```